# depracted map_server warning in launching of move_base node

Tags: c++, navigation, mapping, ros, robotics

I am using navigation stack, map_server, and amcl stack to perform move_base. Before the trajectory planning, I am doing an open-loop SLAM with hector_slam stack and save the map from map_server with my desired resolution and size. However, I am getting a nasty warning after I call the map service to load this map, namely

```
Using deprecated map server interface. please switch to new interface.
```

Why am I getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old `map_server` interface which was `map_server <map> <resolution>`.
The new interafce is `map_server <map.yaml>`, you can view the `map.yaml` format at the [map_server wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format).